# Sending a message to single socket in node.js and socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

How would one send a message out to a single socket using socket.io.

I was thinking something like this but it doesn't work.

```
io.sockets.socket(socket.id).emit('messagetype', "message")
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: Property 'connected' of object #<Namespace> is not a function
```

I think I'm just having an issue with syntax but can't find a source about it.

Comment: If you already have the socket, as in `socket.id`, why not just do `socket.emit('messagetype', "message")` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your code you are usind to feth other persons socket but (socket.id) will always return your own socket id so you have to save others socket id in your database or in any array then you can send them any message:

```
   io.sockets.socket(socket_array['socketid']).emit('','');
```

here socket_array is an array where you have to save others socket id and 'socketid' is the key to feth the socketid;you can use username of others in stead of 'socketid', then it would be an unique id.

Answer (score 1):

Basically this is what you need.

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.emit('messagetype', "message");
});
```

It's well documented at [socketio-docs](http://socket.io/get-started/chat/)